# Azure: Multiple VMs behind same public IP?

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

What is the correct process for getting multiple VMs to report their *public* IP as the same address in Microsoft Azure? I have them in the same subnet on the same VNet already, and there is a gateway on that VNet with a dedicated public IP however all machines are reporting unique public IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general each Azure VM have their own IP (Public or Private or both).
However you can keep one IP at front and VM behind by -

***Option 1*** : Place a azure public loadbalancer and keep the VMs behind this and route the traffic by creating rules.

***Option 2*** : Easy Option if the VMs are identical (same OS, Size etc) you can use the Azure Dev test Lab with shared IP option for multiple VM. This option is there in the advance setting part of create VM dialog, here you can define the instance count as well.
[image]
[image]

Link for DevTestLab - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/tutorial-create-custom-lab

Comment: I was able to get the desired results using a NAT gateway... is there an advantage to a load balancer over that?